# Laravel 5.1 : FatalErrorException in Encrypter.php line 48: Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\mb_strlen()

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I installed laravel 5.1 in my server.
I am getting fatal error like in laravel 5.1 `Call to undefined function Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\mb_internal_encoding()`
then i commented the line `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');` in `LoadConfiguration.php`..

again i am getting one more fatal error

```
Laravel 5.1 : FatalErrorException in Encrypter.php line 48: Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\mb_strlen()
```

can anybody tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Uncomment the line and paste a stacktrace here.

Comment: if i uncomment that line again i m getting the fatal error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\mb_internal_encoding() in /home/wwwideportal/ideinvoice/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php on line 43` @Daan

Comment: Yes now post the stacktrace.

Comment: Did you enable php-mbstring?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is either your PHP installation lacks [multibyte extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php), either it has not been enabled.

If you installed PHP by yourself make sure you compile it with the `--enable-mbstring` option.

If you used your package manager to install PHP then check your php.ini file to enable the mbstring extension.

It may be also possible to install an extra package that contains the extension, depending on your platform

Comment: Actually i did everything in my localhost and I just uploaded my whole website to `go daddy vps hosting server` .after that i am getting this error. Even I enabled php version to 5.5 for laravel 5.1. but i am not getting how to resolve this error. please help me out

Comment: Contact GoDaddy and ask them how to enable mbstring PHP extension. Nothing we can do here

Comment: Yeah i did the same i called up those guys they were telling like its not from our end you need to create a `php.ini`  file and upload to server. what  can i do?